# Regex not working to match any word in a list

Tags: c#, regex

```
Regex r = new Regex(Regex.Escape("(st)"));
//or Regex r=new Regex(@"\(st\)");
int c = r.Matches("test string").Count;
```

The result should be c=2, but c is 0. https://regex101.com/ also gives 2 matches.

Regex("st") will give 2 matches with no doubt. But what is needed here is to match a word in a list and after the failure, to be simple the above test code has only one entry.

Comment: `c` will be 2 if you use `Regex r = new Regex("st");`. Why do you use `Regex.Escape`?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew After using too much Regex.Escape, I stucked in a place where every string containing special character should be escaped...

Comment: So, what is the real problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've done wrong here, is passed your pattern through `Regex.Escape`.
What this will do, is escape your brackets so your pattern will actually be `@"\(st\)"`.

When working with Regular expressions, I like to use [verbatim string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim).
This means you can write the pattern as you need, including backslashes.
Change your code to the following:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(st)");
```

And your regular expression will match.

As an added bonus, using C#'s verbatim strings means you can copy-paste your pattern from sites like Regexr.com without worrying about escaping them.
Only becomes a problem when you're using quotes (`"`), but even then there's ways around that are easy.

---

**EDIT**
If you're looking to match the word at it's boundary, you will need to use \b.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(st\b)"); // Or remove the brackets entirely, up to you.
```

If you're looking to match a word beginning with the string, use `\w` (for word).

[Regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) has a great cheat sheet that's worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

You should not *escape* `(` and `)`; either use `"st"` pattern or `"(st)"` (a *group* which contains `"st"`).

Let's have a look what's going on

```
string test = "test string";

string[] patterns = new string[] {
  "st",                 // just "st"
  "(st)",               // a group which contains "st"
  Regex.Escape("st"),   // just "st" (nothing to escape)
  Regex.Escape("(st)")  // ( and ) are escaped, now we are looking for "(st)" substring
}

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, patterns
  .Select(pattern => 
     $"pattern: {pattern,-10} : matches : {Regex.Matches(test, pattern).Count}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
pattern: st         : matches : 2 // Just "st"
pattern: (st)       : matches : 2 // A group contains "st"
pattern: st         : matches : 2 // Escaped "st" we have nothing to escape
pattern: \(st\)     : matches : 0 // Escaped '(' and ')' which are not matched
```